# How to automate toggle buttons in appium?

Tags: java, appium-ios

I want to automate this toggle buttons in a iOS app with appium.
My script is in java.
What should be the function for this?

html solutions are not addressing here.
This is asking for appium ios solutions.

[I want to toggle the button sound and effects here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L53r.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple toggle buttons html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828998/multiple-toggle-buttons-html)

Comment: @SanjitKumarMishra nope. I'm looking for appium ios solution.

Comment: @SandarekhaRamanayaka get the list of toggle buttons and use index to get each one and perform actions